# Is it possible to create an offline only React Native app?

Tags: react-native

I would like to know if it is possible to create an offline only app with React Native. I'm trying to develop a Calendar App without any API conectivity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's very doable. You'll have to save events locally, on the device, instead of using a back-end and a database. One downside of this would be the inability to share events across devices.

If you want to include events from the user's Google, Apple or other calendars then you will definitely need some kind of internet access.

Comment: I got it. But my question is more technical. What you mean with save events locally? Some kind of native database in the device? Or React Native has it?

Comment: Exactly, there are many different on-device databases for React Native, if you need something even simpler you can look at Async Storage (key-value persistent device storage).

Comment: Nice, thank you Yanick. Could you recommend me a on-device database?

Comment: You should look at something like [WatermelonDB](https://github.com/Nozbe/WatermelonDB)